Laser pointer sensing array
Have you ever came across some kind of electronic array that can sense laser pointer device from a distance of 10-15 meters? Something that works similar to touch screen, but for light point instead of touch point. I was thinking about using photodiodes or photoresistors but soldering them in an array will be too time consuming. Maybe there is a simpler solution?

What wavelength laser? And what is the illuminated surface? A camera with a vision system could work.

what's the size / resolution of your desired photosensitive surface?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

An array that detects the spatial position of light is a camera. You don't need to build one from scratch, you probably already have one. Get a white wall, piece of cardboard, a sheet, a projector screen, etc and point the camera at the surface. Wherever the laser hits will make bright pixels in the camera image.

Have you ever came across some kind of electronic array? ... please do not chat, this site is not a forum ... ask questions about the problem,  not about people's findings

What about using a camera watching the target area? I used a fast flashing laser pointer and scanned the video frames for this pattern in a gaming context.
